# Call to parent operator << C++

Tags: c++

I'm Using C++.

I'm trying to override opeator << as follow (H File):

```
friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Worker& obj);
```

Cpp:

```
ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Worker & obj)
{
    return os << "First Name: " << obj.GetFirstName() << ", Last Name: " << obj.GetLastName() << " ,ID: " << obj.GetID() << ", WorkPlace: " << obj._workPlace << endl;
}
```

Using:

```
Person *w2 = new Worker("First Name", "Last Name", "123456789", "String");

cout << w2;
```

But the operator << Isn't called.

What is the mistake?

Thanks!.

Comment: You want `cout << *w2;`.

Comment: You supply `Person*` instead of `Person`.

Comment: Avoid pointers and `new`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `std::cout << w2;` instead of `std::cout << *w2;` error has hidden the bigger issue: you are trying to use polymorphism by overriding `operator<<` (Call to parent operator <<), however, this isn't overriding but overloading, so `friend ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Worker& obj)` won't be called for `Person` even if the `Person` pointer actually points to a `Worker` object.

The polymorphism solution is to overload `operator<<` for the base class which calls a virtual function that can be overriden by a derived class.

```
struct Base
{
    virtual std::string toString() { return "Base"; }
}

struct Derived: Base
{
    virtual std::string toString() { return "Derived"; }
}

ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & os, const Base & obj)
{
    return os << obj.toString() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`w2` is a pointer to a `Person` object, while your `operator<<` expects a const reference. You can either write another `<<` operator that takes a `Person*` or use

```
cout << *w2;
```

Answer (score 0):

> But the `operator<<` Isn't called.
>
> What is the mistake?

Because you pass a pointer (e.g. an address) and that's what you'll get in your output.

Since you have `operator<<` for a `Worker`, you have to do it this way:

```
Worker *w2 = new Worker("First Name", "Last Name", "123456789", "String");
cout << *w2;
```

or, you may cast back from `Person` to `Worker` if you are sure that the actual object is a `Worker`:

```
Person *w2 = new Worker("First Name", "Last Name", "123456789", "String");
cout << *(Worker*)w2;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't overriding; you override virtual member functions. This is *overloading* and which function to call is determined from the variable's type at compile-time, not from the object's type at runtime.

So assuming that `Worker` inherits from `Person`, even using `*w2` won't work, since that's a `Person&` and not a `Worker&`.

Add a virtual output function in the base class and override that, and replace the parent operator with one that only calls this function.

```
class Person
{
    public:
    // ...
        virtual void write(std::ostream& os);
    };

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Person& p)
{
    p.write(os);
    return os;
}

class Worker : public Person
{
    public:
    // ...
        void write(std::ostream& os) override;
};
```

You don't need any other operator than the one for the base class.